# Missing 'who can answer' channels

Tags: bug, google-chrome

Went to answer [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30900919/multiple-alignments-inside-button), and found this peculiar bug, just below the question:

[image]

This bug seems to be specific to Google Chrome, as I can see the full range of options in Internet Explorer (for once!). I have the standard browser extensions: Adblock, Tampermonkey, etc.

Could this be fixed?

Comment: Oh lawd... I's confused.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This issue lied with Adblock misidentifying the `Google+`, `Facebook`, and `Twitter` links (and text) as advertising, most likely because they're social links.

Adblock was showing a total of **6** elements being blocked:

[image]

as soon as I disabled Adblock, the social links were visible:

[image]

<strike>The solution to this issue is to **disable Adblock**, and</strike>

Adblock no longer interferes with this, it seems that the links have been added to Adblock Plus' whitelist. Also, let's face it, advertising on Stack Overflow (and Stack Exchange overall) is pretty non-intrusive; there's nothing much to gain from blacklisting Stack Overflow/Stack Exchange apart from fixing some client-side site issues.